# Comparing two date values in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, e2e-testing

I'm trying to check if one date value that I get from the element in the app is less than today's date:

```
 const todaysDate = Cypress.moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY')

  it("Check date to be less or equal than todays", () => {
      cy.get('.date', { timeout: 15000 }).eq(3).invoke('text').should('be.lte', todaysDate);
    })
```

However I'm getting the following error:

```
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected '12/14/2020' to be a number or a date
```

Is there a way to convert the date I get from element to a datetime object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use what JavaScript has to offer:

```js
const date = new Date('12/14/2020');
```

so in the context of Cypress:

```js
it("Check date to be less or equal than today", () => {
    cy
      .get('.date', { timeout: 15000 })
      .invoke('text')
      .then(dateText => {
        const date = new Date(dateText);
        const today = new Date();
        
        expect(date).to.be.lte(today);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The moment library is deprecated, using *dayjs* is recommended instead. You'll need this when parsing custom date formats, which might not be supported by the Javascript Date constructor. Based upon your error message I assume the expected format should be `MM/DD/YYYY` instead of `DD/MM/YYY`.

```
it("Check date to be less or equal than todays", () => {
    cy.get('.date', { timeout: 15000 }).invoke('text').then(actualDateText => {
        const dayjs = require('dayjs');
        const todaysDate = new Date();
        const actualDate = dayjs(actualDateText, 'MM/DD/YYYY').toDate();

        expect(actualDate).to.be.lte(todaysDate);
    });
});
```